# Capacitor spike

Tags: capacitor, low-power

For (Marklin) model train wagon lighting I use a 470uF capacitor to avoid flickering over dead spots. The power supply is max 5A and gives 18V.

I have many of these capacitors (20+.)  I was told too many would trip the transformer. They keep the light on for about 1 second without external power.

How do I calculate the maximum number of capacitors before tripping?

---

Here a picture of the setup. Wires get 18V digitalAC from the track. It is then rectified to DC and voltage reduced for LED power.

[image]

Comment: What is the ESR of the capacitor? What is the resistance of the wires between the power supply and capacitor? The sum of these two things combined give you the R. You know V as that's the 18V from your power supply. And you know that I is limited to 5. As a full discharged capacitor (which is the worst case situation you are looking at here) is a short circuit, you now have all the information to put it in to V=IR.

Comment: What is the current rating of your power supply?

Comment: We'd want to know *a lot more* about the power supply internal circuits. A 5A current spec might mean that >5A causes overheating. Or 5A may mean that you get less than 18V for high current. Or 5A may be the point where a fuse blows.

Comment: 5A max current.

Comment: The Switched Mode Power supply is 50/60 VA, 100 - 240 Volts; i use 110V.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of the wiring in a wagon? There are probably options to overcome such limitations with additional resistor and diode.

Comment: @Jens - Hi, FYI photo has now been added.

Comment: If you're modelling older trains, flickering over dead spots is actually quite realistic!

Answer (score 1):

If your light current is low, you can add a resistor in series with the caps. The value of R1 should be high enough to limit the current to a safe level, and low enough so the voltage drop to the light is negligible.

Based on your capacitance and hold-up time of 1 sec, the light current is somewhere around 50 mA. Measure it if you can to confirm.

Peak current = 18 V / 5 ohms = 3.6 A (worst case when the cap voltage is zero and power is applied)

Voltage drop during normal operation = 0.05 A * 5 ohms = 0.25 V.

Edit: Updated schematic based on new info.

Edit2: you changed the question slightly, so ...

With an appropriate resistor added, there is no limit to the size of the capacitor. Without adding a resistor, the cap limit is difficult to determine because of the many unknowns. You say that the power source is 5 amps, I assume that is continuous. Does it have a surge rating? There are probably other engines/cars on the track. An engine will probably draw a few amps. Lookup the current draw of your engine(s).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUlR6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make modifications at your PCB, you can add a resistor and a diode between the positive contact of capacitor and PCB. It will soft charge the capacitor via R1 with a bit more than 80 mA peak, protecting the wheel contacts. The diode feeds the LEDs during dropouts.

This is not perfect, but easy to implement and avoids high transformer loads and wheel arcing.

It is absolute possible, that something like this is already part of the circuit of your PCB, but I could not find a schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG4OfL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'll do this, as it seems most straightforward. Would a 100 ohm 1/2W resister do the job too?  Someone else recommended that, differering from your 220O/1W.

Comment: @BenvanderPluijm The peak power for 100 ohm would be 3.24 W in this circuit, critical for a typical 0.5 W resistor, but there are special wire wound types with short time overload factor 10 available.